# snprintf() without format specifier?

Tags: c, printf

I am writing a code like this using `snprintf()`:

```
char myId[10] = "id123";

char duplicateId[10] = "";

snprintf(duplicateId, 10, myId);
```

As you can see, I am not specifying the format specifier `%s` explicitly.

Do I need to explicitly specify the format specifier in the above `snprintf()` statement like this `snprintf(duplicateId, 10, "%s", myId);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't have to, technically. But it's better practice to do so, because without a constant format string, your format string remains modifiable thus your code will be more prone to format string attacks.

Ah, and also use `sizeof(duplicateId)` instead of a constant `10` - also for security reasons (in order to avoid future buffer overflows when changing the size of the output buffer of sprintf).

Answer (score 2):

No you dont, but it's generally considered a good idea especially if there's any chance of passing user-input text to `snprintf()`. If the user enters a string with `%` in it otherwise, there will be trouble:

```
const char *userString = "%";
snprintf(duplicateId, sizeof duplicateIt, userString);  /* BAD */

const char *userString = "%s";
snprintf(duplicateId, sizeof duplicateIt, "%s", userString);  /* GOOD. */
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be better to use `%s` since it is more secured... Don't you get a warning for this?
try to compile in the highest warning level, as well.

read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string)